# Choose, Import and Text Delimit Txt Files

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter, csv

Very new to excel VBA here. Tried building a code to choose, import and delimit txt files, and I am stuck.

Basically, each txt file will be in the same format and areas where I will need to limit, thanks alot for the help!

```
fileToOpen = Application _ 
 .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt") 

Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _ 
 ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(61, 1), Array(102, 1), Array(120, 1), Array( _
        126, 1), Array(131, 1), Array(143, 1), Array(153, 1), Array(162, 1), Array(173, 1), Array( _
        188, 1), Array(201, 1), Array(212, 1), Array(231, 1), Array(250, 1), Array(267, 1), Array( _
        284, 1), Array(296, 1), Array(304, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: **I am stuck** does not do a good job of explaining the problem you are having.  But I can see that your `FieldInfo` entries are not compatible with your `DataType`.  Also, if your `DataType` is `xlDelimited`, you never specifiy a delimiter.  Perhaps your data type should be `xlFixedWidth`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the TextToColumns command is correctly configure, you just need to make sure that you open the text file as a new workbook and specify the correct range to operate.

You can try this for instance:

```
Dim fileToOpen As String
fileToOpen = Application _
 .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
 
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileToOpen)

wb.Activesheet.UsedRange.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
 ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(61, 1), Array(102, 1), Array(120, 1), Array( _
        126, 1), Array(131, 1), Array(143, 1), Array(153, 1), Array(162, 1), Array(173, 1), Array( _
        188, 1), Array(201, 1), Array(212, 1), Array(231, 1), Array(250, 1), Array(267, 1), Array( _
        284, 1), Array(296, 1), Array(304, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```